# Tkinter canvas window not working?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a text based adventure that prints labels of game text to the screen. I need to make the window scrollable so I am attempting to implement a canvas, containing a frame, which contains the labels. 
For some reason when I do this:

```
display = Tk()
display.geometry('1000x800')

canvas = Canvas(display)
frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.pack()
frame.pack()
```

The labels are packed properly, but obviously can't be scrolled.
However when I do this (Create a frame window in the canvas):

```
canvas = Canvas(display)
frame = Frame(canvas, width=1000, height=700)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')
```

The first label does not fit in the frame, and after the second one is printed they all just disappear?

Labels of game text are printed as this function is called throughout the main game loop:

```
def output(text):
    l = Label(frame,text=text,justify=LEFT,font=font)
    l.pack()
    display.update()
```

I've been fiddling with container dimensions and some pack() attributes, however nothing seems to be working. The window's dimensions don't seem to change based on the frame's. 
I should be able to add a scrollbar if i can just get these to draw properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this what youre looking for? http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Yeah, but in order to implement the scrollbar I need a working frame in a canvas, and that's not really happening right now haha.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Don't reproduce all of your code, just take what's in the question, and add a few more lines to make a complete program.